# Image disappears when using \textwidth or \columnwidth

Tags: graphics, floats, textwidth, scale

I am trying to insert an image in my document using one of the relative scales, such as `\columnwidth` or `\textwidth`. When I use one of them, the image disappears, but the label is present on the text:
[image: Figure disappears]

```
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=\columnwidth]{LaTeX/images/test-image.png}}
\caption{This is a test image.}
\label{ux1}
\end{figure*}
```

However, if I set the scale to a number, such as `0.30`:

[image]

```
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{LaTeX/images/test-image.png}}
\caption{This is a test image.}
\label{ux1}
\end{figure*}
```

The same happens when I use the `figure` environment (without the *) for a single-column image. Since this is a template, I am not sure if I am allowed to change the document's structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: (i) replace `\centerline{....}` with `\centering` (ii) `scale=<number>` not `scale=\textwidth`, (iii) image width can be set by `width=<width>`. Please, provide an MWE with your image, that we can more easy answer/show you a solution.

Comment: \columnwidth is a length and not suitable for the scale key, use `width=\columnwidth`.